# A PHP DOM program to import Freemind document in database

Tags: php, mysql, dom, freemind

I put my code after some explanations.

I program this because i need to fill a database used by an application with .mm document (Freemind docs, .mm is the extension for "mind mapping")

The application and database need i keep the structure inside the Freemind doc. I don't program the application and the database, it's the work of an another guy.

This is the reason because i have all this
"if the child of the current node is a node with a child is an icon with an attribute called BUILTIN contains idea, this child is not an other object to put in the database, but the "contenu" value of the object create by the current node"

Just horrible to explain (it's horrible to explain it in French... And i try to make it clear in English. I hope it's clear.)

When i try to use my program, i can select the Freemind docs i want to convert is SQL, but i have this error just after:
   Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in C:\xampp\htdocs\test2\transfertXmlBdd.php on line 25

Someone know why it's doesn't work and how i can make it works?

I think it's this part

```
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    $chaineXML = $target_file;
```

I try to keep the uploaded file in the $chaineXML for charge it with DOM after.

```
$dom->loadXML($chaineXML);
```

But i probably do it wrong.

uploadForm

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Selectionner le document Freemind a charger:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Charger le document" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

upload

```
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
//if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
//    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
//    if($check !== false) {
//        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
//        $uploadOk = 1;
//    } else {
//        echo "File is not an image.";
//        $uploadOk = 0;
//    }
//}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Le fichier a deja ete charger.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
//if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 50000000) {
//    echo "Le fichier est trop lourd.";
//    $uploadOk = 0;
//}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "mm") {
    echo "Vous ne pouvez upload que des fichiers XML au format MM (mind mapping).";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Echec du chargement.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        $chaineXML = $target_file;
        echo "Le fichier ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " a ete charger.";

        //on appelle la conversion/transfert
        include_once('C:/xampp/htdocs/test2/transfertXmlBdd.php');
        echo "Les donnees ont ete enregistre dans la BDD.";
    } else {
        echo "Une erreur s'est produite.";
    }
}
?>
```

transferXmlBdd

```
$dom->loadXML($chaineXML);

$element = $listeElements->item(0);

//variables
$id= NULL;
$nom = NULL;
$type = NULL;
$contenu = NULL;
$idParent = NULL;
$idFils = NULL;

//comper le nombres d'elements déjà présent dans la table
$res = $bdd->query('select count(*) as nb from element');
$data = $res->fetch();
$id = $data['nb'];

foreach($xml as $node)
{
    //on vérifie la présence ou non de BUILTIN de valeur idea, on passe à l'itération suivante (en forçant) si oui
    if($node->hasChild("icon")->hasAttribute("BUILTIN")="idea")
    {
        continue;
    }

    //on génere les valeurs id et nom
    $nom = getAttributeNode('NAME');
    $id = $id + 1;
    $idFils = $id;
    //
    $node.setAttribute(bddid,$id);

    //on vérifie la parenté de l'enregistrement
    if($node->hasParent("node"))
    {
        $idParent = getAttributeParent('bddid');
        $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO fils_des_element(id_elem, id_fils) VALUES( idParent, :idFils)');
    }
    else
    {
        // affilié à l'élement 0
        $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO fils_des_element(id_elem, id_fils) VALUES( 0, :idFils)');
    }

    //vérification de contenu
    if($node->hasChild("node")->hasChild("icon")->hasAttribute("BUILTIN")=idea)
    {
        $contenu = getChildAttribute('NAME');
    }

    //détermination du type
    if($node->hasChild("icon")-hasAttribute("BUILTIN")=button_ok)
    {
        $type = "Avec Solution";
    }
    elseif($node->hasChild("icon")-hasAttribute("BUILTIN")=button_cancel)
    {
        $type = "Sans Solution";
    }
    else
    {
        $type = NULL;
    }

    //création de l'entré dans la table
    $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO element(id_element, nom, type, proprietaire, visible, contenu, date_modif) VALUES( :id, :nom, :type, drn, 0, :contenu, CURDATE())');
}

?>
```

Comment: You have to fix you question: The line number of the error doesn't match the script - transferXmlBdd seems to be incomplete.

Comment: @vboerchers tranferXmlBdd is not incomplete, but some lines dont appears here (and i try to fix it, twice)

And after check, some test and modifications the part of code i think it doesn't work look ok (in start i think the error appears because the xml file is not properly charged).

I think i can fix the error, but i don't have the time to test it yesterday, because other things to do, but i try it as soon as possible and edit my questions after.